# ESP32 library conflicts, EEPROM, SPIFFS and IR

Tags: esp32, eeprom, spiffs

Using an Adafruit HAZZAH ESP32, I discovered (the hard way) the well-known conflict between the `EEPROM.h` and `IRremote.h` libraries.

Causes a memory conflict and a reboot. I tried moving over to using `SPIFFS.h` and got it working without the `IRremote.h` library, but when I included using that library, I got the same reboot behavior.

If I comment out the line  **`myIRrcvr.enableIRIn();`** and run the code, the `SPIFFS` stuff works fine. Problem is, there is no `.disableIRIn()` that I know of. I'm new at this, and I don't know if there is another way to disable or remove the instance of `mIRrcvr` before using SPIFFS, and then re-enable it or reestablish it.

Any ideas?